# Thermal printer with Raspberry Pi 2 outputs only Chinese chars

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, printing

Following thermal printer + raspi2 tutorial for printing images (https://learn.adafruit.com/networked-thermal-printer-using-cups-and-raspberry-pi/connect-and-configure-printer), I've already connected the TTL printer through TX and RX serial connections. Also succesfully added as a printer (Zijiang ZJ-58 -> serial:/dev/ttyAMA0?baud=9600), and print test page when I click on test page print, but, the problem is when I try to send a "Hello world. test" or an image file through CUPS. The data is sent, but what **I have as output is a endless bunch of Chinese chars:**

[image: printer output]

Code sent for the output from image:

```
$ lpr -o fit-to-page raspberry-pi-logo.pdf
```

I'm using Raspbian. Raspberry Pi 2. CUPS libraries.
Also tried with and without adding a 1Kohm resistor on Rx and Tx wires.

Is there any issue? Is there something that need to be calibrated? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It might be useful to find out if this is jibberish or meaningful -- I tried the image [here](http://www.i2ocr.com/free-online-chinese-simplified-ocr) but it did not work; possibly if you try with a straight on, cropped, right side up, minimal length segment it might work better.   I think the three 8's are very lucky, BTW.

Comment: Thanks @goldilocks , I've reached the supplier, he says it could be fixed with a firmware upgrade (as I've understood...) Let's see what they send me to fix... By the way, many thanks for your time, I'll keep you posted.

Comment: it may just be an error message that we cant read since we dont speak the language

Comment: The combination of characters mixed in with spurious spacing, question marks, euro symbols, and other both Latin and Chinese characters tells me that's probably a red herring, @MohammadAli

Comment: http://scruss.com/blog/2015/07/12/thermal-printer-driver-for-cups-linux-and-raspberry-pi-zj-58/ might help

Answer (score 2):

***Question***

> How come my AdaFruit thermal printer prints only Chinese characters, How
>   to fix?

***Answer***

[image: thermal printer]

> (1) The printer seems to have set to talk Chinese.  Your "Hello World"
>   sounds rubbish to it. The printer is returning rubbish Chinese
>   characters.  They are indeed Chinese characters, but meaningless
>   rubbish, not error message or something like that.
>
> (2) The printer talks many languages, ***You can set it to English (User
>   Guide Section 5, Ref 3 below）***
>
> (3) I guess the serial TTL communication (9600, 8N1, I guess) setup is
>   OK, only initialization not OK.  User guide has command set to do
>   testing, eg, Line Feed, etc to do basic testing.
>
> (4)  I use and modify Chinese character (serial RS232 12V) and parallel
>   (Centronic) inkjet/dot matrix printers (HP/Epson/Brother), and Chinese
>   characters and graphics LCD (640 x 480).  I am pretty sure that what I
>   am saying is correct.

***References***

(1) [AdaFruit Mini Thermal Receipt Printer (ASCII, GB2312-80) $50](https://www.adafruit.com/product/597)

(2) [AdaFruit Mini Thermal Receipt Printer Tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/mini-thermal-receipt-printer)

(3) [AdaFRuit Mini Thermal Receipt Printer User Manual](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/A2-user+manual.pdf)

(4) [SparkFun Thermal Printer $55](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14970)

(5) [How to create and connect a virtual printer via RS232? - tlfong01](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99500/how-to-create-and-connect-a-virtual-printer-via-rs232)

(6) [Python GPIO Interface to Epson Inkjet Printer - tlfong01](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99262/outb-equivalent-in-python-for-gpio/99268#99268)